# How do I style two buttons to line up together in glamorous?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, glamorous

I am getting my hands into glamorous, which is a React component styling module. I have two buttons that I am trying to style: `Add` and `Clear`. I am attempting to have the two buttons on the same row with the `Clear` button on the left and `Add` button on the right. I am having trouble making the two buttons on the same row. Instead, the `Clear` button is underneath the `Add` button. This is what I have:

```
import * as React from "react";
import glamorous from "glamorous";
import { CSSProperties } from "glamorous/typings/css-properties";
import { graphql, InjectedGraphQLProps } from "react-apollo";
import { reduxForm, Field, FormProps, WrappedFieldProps } from "redux-form";
import { ItemListQuery, AddItemMutation, AddItemMutationVariables } from "../queries/types";

const Form = glamorous.form({
  display: "flex",
  flexFlow: "column nowrap",
  maxWidth: 320,
  "> *": { margin: "1 1 30px" }
});

const Label = glamorous.label({
  display: "flex",
  flexFlow: "column-reverse",
  "> :first-child": { marginTop: 5 }
});

const sharedInputStyles: CSSProperties = {
  backgroundColor: "#e9e9e9",
  border: "none",
  borderBottom: "2px solid #e9e9e9",
  padding: 6,
  outline: "none",
  transition: "all .2s ease-in",
  ":focus": {
    borderBottom: "2px solid #777",
  },
  fontSize: 14,
  fontWeight: 200
};

const ItemInput = glamorous.input(
  sharedInputStyles,
  { height: 24 }
);

const Button = glamorous.button({
  height: 40,
  backgroundColor: "#bababa",
  border: "none",
  outline: "none",
  ":focus": { border: "2px solid #777" },
  ":active": {
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    border: "2px solid #dcdcdc"
  }
});

const ItemField = ({ input }: WrappedFieldProps<{}>) => (
  <ItemInput {...input} />
);

export interface AddItemProps extends
  InjectedGraphQLProps<{}>,
  FormProps<Partial<Item>, undefined, undefined> {
}

const AddItem = ({ handleSubmit }: AddItemProps) => (
  <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <Label>
      Name
      <Field name="name" component={ItemField} />
    </Label>
    <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
    <Button type="submit">Reset</Button>
  </Form>
);
```

I tried adding `display: "inline"` to the Button component like this:

```
const Button = glamorous.button({
  height: 40,
  backgroundColor: "#bababa",
  display: "inline",
  border: "none",
  outline: "none",
  ":focus": { border: "2px solid #777" },
  ":active": {
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    border: "2px solid #dcdcdc"
  }
});
```

It did not do anything. Next, I tried changing it to `display: "inline-block"`:

```
const Button = glamorous.button({
  height: 40,
  backgroundColor: "#bababa",
  display: "inline-block",
  border: "none",
  outline: "none",
  ":focus": { border: "2px solid #777" },
  ":active": {
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    border: "2px solid #dcdcdc"
  }
});
```

Finally, I tried to add `overflow: "auto"` to the Button component:

```
const Button = glamorous.button({
  height: 40,
  backgroundColor: "#bababa",
  display: "inline-block",
  overflow: "auto",
  border: "none",
  outline: "none",
  ":focus": { border: "2px solid #777" },
  ":active": {
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    border: "2px solid #dcdcdc"
  }
});
```

It did not work as well. All my attempts did not do anything to the buttons. How can I place the buttons on the same row that is evenly spaced on the form?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while, but maybe it will help someone:

The problem is in the `Form` element. It has style of flex column, that's why it positions its children on new lines. If you add a wrapper around buttons, even a simple div, they would behave as you expect them:

```
const AddItem = ({ handleSubmit } ) => (
  <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <Label>
      Name
      <ItemField />
    </Label>
    <div>
      <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
      <Button type="submit">Reset</Button>
    </div>
  </Form>
);
```

Here is a slightly modified code snippet:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vgnjjz